# i want output of table like - first three values of the field should show in table of three columns and next three values in next row of table

Tags: html, sql, asp.net

i have table

| id | desciption |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 2 | two |
| 3 | three |
| 4 | four |
| 5 | five |
| 6 | six |

want output like

| D1 | D2 | D3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | two | three |
| four | five | six |

and so on

I want to create a buttons - dynamically using table values for every value of same field.

3 buttons should be in one row and so on.

Comment: So, what is your question exactly? Which part of this are you struggling with? Getting the sql in the format you want? Or creating the buttons? Are you getting exceptions? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This looks like a UI issue as retrieving the data in the format of the table looks to be reasonable. When you parse over the data returned, just iterate over it in multiples of three or use a counter to create a new row of buttons after three iterations.

Answer (score 0):

For such types of code, in most cases using a repeater makes sense. However, let's try/go with a GridView.

So, say this markup:

```
        <div style="float:left">

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            CssClass="table table-hover" Width="500px"
            >
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="D1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="B1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("B1") %>' 
                            CssClass="btn myshadow"
                            OnClick="B1_Click"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="D2">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="B2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("B2") %>' 
                            CssClass="btn myshadow"
                            OnClick="B1_Click"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="D3">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="B3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("B3") %>' 
                            CssClass="btn myshadow"
                            OnClick="B1_Click"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:35px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

        </div>
```

And then code to fill is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If

End Sub


Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim rstData As DataTable =
        MyRst("SELECT ID, Description FROM tblBut ORDER BY ID")

    Dim rstFlatTable As New DataTable

    rstFlatTable.Columns.Add("B1")
    rstFlatTable.Columns.Add("B2")
    rstFlatTable.Columns.Add("B3")

    Dim iColumns As Integer = 3     ' number of columns
    Dim iColPtr As Integer = 0      ' our colum ptr

    Dim NewRow As DataRow = rstFlatTable.NewRow

    For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstData.Rows

        If iColPtr < iColumns Then
            NewRow(iColPtr) = OneRow("Description")
        Else ' start a new row
            rstFlatTable.Rows.Add(NewRow)
            iColPtr = 0
            NewRow = rstFlatTable.NewRow
            NewRow(iColPtr) = OneRow("Description")
        End If
        iColPtr += 1
    Next

    ' add last row straggler
    rstFlatTable.Rows.Add(NewRow)


    GridView1.DataSource = rstFlatTable
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And the button click event code is this:

```
Protected Sub B1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Label1.Text = $"button click value = {btn.Text}"

    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer
    Label2.Text = $"Row index click = {gRow.RowIndex}"

End Sub
```

So, result when run is this:

[image]

Using a repeater would also work rather nice.

About the only addition to above would be a wee bit of code in the row data bound event to hide the extra buttons on that last row.

In above, I used a "helper" routine, since I fast became tired of typing in code to create a table based on given SQL. So, that helper routine was this:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable
    ' general get any data from SQL

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function
```

And the style for the cute button was this:

```
    <style>
        .myshadow {
            box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px 0px gray;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: solid;
            border-color: lightgray;
            border-width: .1em;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        .myshadow:hover {background-color:#789eca;transition: 0.5s;}
    </style>
```